# debug.log in CakePHP without stacktrace

Tags: debugging, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I log values of variables into debug.log using:

```
$var = 'Hello World';
debugger::log($var);
```

in my `/app/tmp/logs/debug.log` there is the whole stacktrace for that log:

```
2014-03-24 20:47:42 Debug: 
UserController::create() - APP\Controller\UserController.php, line 21
ReflectionMethod::invokeArgs() - [internal], line ??
Controller::invokeAction() - CORE\Cake\Controller\Controller.php, line 490
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php, line 185
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php, line 160
[main] - APP\webroot\index.php, line 108
'Hello World'
```

I don´t need the stacktrace, only the value of my variable.

Comment: I think you are using debugger plugin of cake.. Have you tried simply $this->log($var);

Comment: @Anand Ghaywankar the statement '$this->log($var);' logs into error.log. I want to log into debug.log.

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions is to use CakeLog::write function

```
CakeLog::write(LOG_DEBUG, "your message");
```

You will get the output to debug.log file:

```
2014-07-21 16:08:25 Debug:
your message
```

---

It is impossible to remove stack trace from debugger::log($var). Why? Here is its CakePHP code from Debugger.php:

```
public static function log($var, $level = LOG_DEBUG, $depth = 3) {
    $source = self::trace(array('start' => 1)) . "\n";
    CakeLog::write($level, "\n" . $source . self::exportVar($var, $depth));
}
```

Or edit the CakePHP source :)